# Excel 2010 VBA - How to AddShape an exact square in metric

Tags: vba, excel-2010, scaling, metrics, vector-graphics

I want to generate simple, exact vector shapes in metric. However when doing:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 1000, 1000).Select
```

Excel draws a rectangle that upon inspection is H 352,78 mm W 358,07 mm. Height is correct, it's the width that is the problem.

AddShape works with points and I need to convert input with

```
Application.CentimetersToPoints()/10
```

Above kind of sucks, it's messy, I don't like working in points, but I can bypass it.

I don't want it getting messier by rescaling each axis individually on top of that.

Comment: I tried it in points and cm and the widht is OK. Maybe you are inserting a column or stratching a comlumn somewhere after inserting the square that modifies the width?? (If columns o rows are stretched before the insertion that does not affect, and the width is ok)

Comment: I readjusted all the rows and columns and it works perfectly now! You've helped me saved hours of work, thank you!